# VBA Add comma after every second space

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I am trying to create a linestring from coordinates using a userform and add a comma after every second space but cannot achieve it

example or raw data

```
-2.4971431, 51.5176693
-2.4971618, 51.5176478
```

example of how i want it to look LINESTRING(-2.4971431 51.5176693, -2.4971618 51.5176478)

the code below removes the comma and line break but i need to add the comma back in after every second space

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
TextBox2 = Replace(TextBox2, ",", " ")
TextBox2 = Replace(TextBox2, vbCrLf, " ")
End Sub
```

Comment: `TextBox2 = Replace(TextBox2, vbCrLf, ", ")`

Comment: Ah so simple, Thank you